# Cauchy-Riemann equation in a Polar form

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have started differentiation  very recently and by the looks of the proof of the Cauchy-Riemann equations in a polar form, I have difficulty converting the following:

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ $cos(Ф)$ - $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ $cos(Ф)$ = $\frac{r}{1}$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial Ф}$

Well, I can try to factor out 1/r from the expression and get

$\frac{1}{r}$ ( $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ $rcos(Ф)$ - $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ $rcos(Ф)$)

but then I cannot equal it to ∂v/∂Ф. Then, I figured out if I could use the Chain Rule, but it takes me nowhere.

Can anybody explain this to me? I will be glad to any feedback.

Also, I am sorry my equations look little unprofessional; I am currently studying how to write these correctly.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
v(r, \Phi) &= v(x(r, \Phi), y(r, \Phi)) \Rightarrow \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial \Phi} &= \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \Phi} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \Phi} = \\
&=\left[
\begin{array}{rl}
x(r, \Phi) = r\cos(\Phi) \Rightarrow & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \Phi} = -r\sin(\Phi) \\
y(r, \Phi) = r\sin(\Phi) \Rightarrow & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \Phi} = r\cos(\Phi) \\
\end{array}
\right] = \\
&= \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\left(-r\sin(\Phi)\right) + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\left(r\cos(\Phi)\right) = \\
&=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}r\cos(\Phi) - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}r\sin(\Phi) 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Few words and explanations would not hurt.